# How to fix the sys.host_summary table in MariaDB 10.3.13

Tags: mariadb, mysqldump, sys

using mysqldump while doing a backup gives the following error:

```
mysqldump: Got error: 1356: "View 'sys.host_summary' references invalid table(s) or column(s) or function(s) or definer/invoker of view lack rights to use them" when using LOCK TABLES
```

What can I do to fix that?

Comment: Where did you get the sys schema from? Did you install it from [here](https://github.com/good-dba/mariadb-sys)? Or maybe you migrated from MySQL to MariaDB, and the sys schema came along somehow?

Comment: Yes, I migrated from MySQL to MariaDB some days ago..

Comment: Probably you need to run `mysql_upgrade`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The sys schema is not bundled with 10.3, but [seems to be planned for 10.5](https://jira.mariadb.org/browse/MDEV-9077). If you don't use/need it, you can safely remove it: `DROP DATABASE sys;`. If you do need it, you need to try resolving the issue outlined in the error message. For a start you can do `SHOW CREATE VIEW sys.host_summary;` to see which tables, views and functions it's referencing, as well as the definer/invoker.

Comment: I don't think I need it, it was just there, because I migrated from Mysql to MariaDB. So its safe to `DROP DATABASE sys;`?

Comment: @JHnet - yes, that's right, you can safely drop it like that.

Comment: drop database sys --> Works for me; thank you